# import words in android personal dictionary

Tags: gboard, dictionary, import

I have a json file exported from a 3rd party app keyboard and I wanted to know if there is any way I can import it in Google Android Dictionary (so that gboard keyboard app can utilize it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I did the job with User Dictionary Manager (UDM)!

Find it in Play-Store.

I just had to transform the json export file to plain text word-by-line file.